# Block the access to a page students.index()

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

In my navbar I have 2 pages which are `Student Add` and `Student Index`.

[image]

When I click on Student Add, I have an error message `Access Denied`. 
Great, no problem...

[image]

Now, I would like to make the even thing with the page `Students Index` and display the items, I have a problem.

I have access to the content...

[image]

In my Controller **Student** I have this:

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{   

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'clearance'])
            ->except('index', 'show');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $students = Student::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('students.index', compact('students'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('students.create');
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'firstname' =>'required',
            ]);

        $name = $request['name'];
        $firstname = $request['firstname'];

        $student = Student::create($request->only('name', 'firstname'));

        return redirect()->route('students.index')
            ->with('flash_message', 'Article,
             '. $student->name.' created');
    }
```

Then, in my Class **ClearanceMiddleware** I have this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {        
        if (Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Administer roles & permissions')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if ($request->is('students/create')) {
            if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Create Student')) {
                abort('401');
            } else {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        if ($request->is('students/index')) {
            if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Index Student')) {
                abort('401');
            } else {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
```

I don't see the missed step. I have to block the access please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1) You need to adjust the middleware call in your controller's constructor. The `except()` method means the middleware will not run on those methods, so if you want the middleware to run on the `index` method, you will need to remove it from `except()`.

This will call the middleware on every route method except `show()`:

```php
$this->middleware(['auth', 'clearance'])
    ->except('show');
```

2) Inside your middleware, you are using `$request->is()` to match on the path, but the url for index is not 'students/index'.

```php
// The url path for the index route is '/students'
if ($request->is('students')) {
    if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Index Student')) {
        abort('401');
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. It works !! I am happy ahhahaah thank you a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$this->middleware(['auth', 'clearance'])
            ->except('show');

Remove index from the except method. As it is you are exempting the index method from the middleware check.

Comment: @F KIng: Thank you but it's not good. I think the problem is in ClearanceMiddleware?

Comment: If I get your question, you want the index method on the controller to use the auth and ClearanceMiddleware right? As your code is currently the index method on the controller is exempted from using the two middlewares since you included it in the except method. Hence the check you have in the Clearance never gets to restrict the access as you intend cause it is never applied on the indec method. Hope this helps.